# How to stop excel convert fractions into dates; also for fractions which equal to 1?

Tags: microsoft-excel

I know the default behavior of Microsoft Excel(Microsoft 365 16.0.14326.20384 64bit) is to convert fractions into data. Stopping the behavior, change the "Format Cells" option to "Fraction" as it instructs on the MS web page:
https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/display-numbers-as-fractions-0121ecac-1773-4f2d-8cd3-7db51fd83b77

Although the circumvent, the fractions whose values are equal to 1 (ex. 3/3, 5/5, etc.) are turned into "44258", which I don't understand what it means...
I want fractions like 3/3, 5/5, etc. displayed.

How can we tell Excel to stop converting fractions into dates (or 44258), whose values are equal to 1?

Comment: 44258 means that's the 44258th day from the epoch (30/12/1899 by default in Execl)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically your 44258 is coming when your cell format is in data mode and you are calculating `3/3` then excel is understanding you are inputting data for data which month number is 03 and data number is 03. I am in a little bit confusion if you want to output your result as 1 or 3/3. If you want to output your result 1 then first format your cells for fraction then input. And if you want to output your result as 3/3 then you have to format your cells for text and input without `=` sign.

Confirm if you have any doubt!

Comment: I want to get like 3/3, 5/5, etc. as displayed. Therefore, I format the cells for text. I understand.